# Bing Search API in PHP - missing webPages property in json response

Tags: php, azure-cognitive-services, bing-search

I am trying to get search results as per the [api documentation](https://dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56b43eeccf5ff8098cef3807/operations/56b4447dcf5ff8098cef380d#php)

Here is what I wrote in PHP

```
    require_once 'HTTP/Request2.php';

    $api_key = 'my_bing_search_api_key';
    $url_encoded_keyword = urlencode('animation concepts and tutorials');


    $request = new \Http_Request2('https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/search');      
    $headers = [
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' => $api_key
    ];        
    $request->setHeader($headers);

    $url = $request->getUrl();

    $parameters = [
        'q' => $url_encoded_keyword,
        'count' => '10',
        'offset' => '0',
        'safesearch' => 'Strict',
    );

    $url->setQueryVariables($parameters);

    $request->setMethod(\HTTP_Request2::METHOD_GET);

    $request->setBody("{body}");

    $search_result = null;
    try {
        $response = $request->send();
        $search_results = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
        return $search_results;
    } catch (HttpException $ex) {            
        return [];
    }
```

I am getting response but it is not having webPages property. It has _type, rankingResponse, relatedSearches and videos properties only.
I tested the same request in the [api console](https://dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56b43eeccf5ff8098cef3807/operations/56b4447dcf5ff8098cef380d/console). There I am getting the webPages property in the json response.

Any ideas what could have been the reason why I am not getting the webPages in PHP but works on microsoft's api tester site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code snippet, you are passing the keyword to Bing web search API after encoding it.
    $url_encoded_keyword = urlencode('animation concepts and tutorials');

```
$parameters = [
    'q' => $url_encoded_keyword,
    'count' => '10',
    'offset' => '0',
    'safesearch' => 'Strict',
);
```

Try without encoding the keyword. From their [API testing console](https://dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56b43eeccf5ff8098cef3807/operations/56b4447dcf5ff8098cef380d/console), HTTP request for the same keyword would appear as

> https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/search?q=animation
>   concepts and tutorials&count=10&offset=0&mkt=en-us&safesearch=Moderate